# Hashmap is null when returning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hashmap

I am having a rest controller to consume a web service like below:

```
@RestController
public class Test {

    public Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restTemplatetest")
    private RestTemplate restTemplatetest;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplatetest() {
        RestTemplateBuilder buildertest = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        RestTemplate buildtest = buildertest.build();

        return buildtest;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
    public void receiveTestData() {
        map.clear();
        map = restTemplatetest.getForObject("url", Map.class);
        // I get the testdata

        System.out.println("size of hashmap after requesting is:" + map.size());// this print s the test data size as 120
    }


    public Map<Integer, Integer> supplyTestData() {

        System.out.println("size of hashmap after requesting is:" + map.size());// this print s the test data size as 0
        return map;
    }
}
```

So I want this test data hash map in another controller

So what I do is

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    Test test;
    Map<Integer, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 40000, initialDelay = 40000)
    public void fetchTestDataHere() {
        testMap = test.supplyTestData();
    }
}
```

But this returns a null.
So my question is I receive the data in the Test Class and it is not null.But when I return the hash map from Test Class it is returning a null value.Why is that?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not see `give_status_map` in the `Test` class

Comment: Sorry it is give_test_data

Comment: Works here http://ideone.com/2BPgGW

Comment: Make a minimal example that can reproduce the problem.  If you cannot make it, then it is something else you haven't disclosed that cause the problem.  And, please pay attention to your coding style.  Indentation, naming etc are all a mess and does not conform to Java's convention

Comment: Where does `restTemplatetaxistatus` come from and what is its value? Clearly, it is returning `null`. Why do you assign a variable one value and then immediately overwrite that value with another assignment?

Comment: As I said the problem is not with the scheduled process.It updates the HashMap and prints the size as 120.But the problem is when i send the Hash Map to the xext Controller

Comment: As @DavidConrad states, `RestTemplateBuilder` is highly suspect. Also, you really need to format the code as pointed out by Adrian Shum. Furthermore, the naming conventions are confusing because, for example, you have a method a `void getX()`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't have a method `void getX()`  .

Comment: I meant `X` as in some arbitrary noun. A method prefixed with get that does not return a value is strange. I see the edit, `fetch` is better for sure

Comment: You have to make the map static so that it will be there irrespective of the Test object instance.

Comment: So what I don't understand is that I have my public HashMap updated in the sheduled `receiveTestData` but it is empty when I access in the method `supplyTestData`.What causes the hash map to be empty? Do I need to Autowire any other methods?

Comment: @user3701844 thanks a lot.It solved the problem when i made the map static.

Comment: In your code you show both `testmap` and `testMap`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because Map is tied to the instance of Test object and if you want to access it by auto wiring it, you have to make it static.